# Problems to reindex a df - Cannot ccast array from int64 to int 32 according to the rule "safe"

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to reindex a dataframe, which worked on my old laptop but now I have some trouble reindex the df on my other laptop.
I get following Error Msg:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

this line has the error:

```
new_df=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.U_REVIEW.str.len()))
```

I tried to put in the end of this Code line :

```
.astype('int32' )  
.astype(numpy.int32)
```

but I still have the same error.
does anyone else knows, how to fix this problem?

Comment: This works on version 0.22. You may want to upgrade.

Comment: Im using this version